# Can I use Split() on an array in Perl ? I am looking for a regex on the array elements

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, split, duplicates

I am trying to get the names of the image files on my local machine and also that It should not be repeated. I have got all the file names in an array and when I try to go in the array and use Split() I get some 888 as output. I am looking for a regex where I can print everything before the '_'(underscore) encountered. I need to get the names and then I can use Uniq to remove the duplicates. Any suggestions are welcomed.

I have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::MoreUtils qw/ uniq /;

my $localdir = 'images/p/';
my @filefound;

find(
  sub {push @filefound, $File::Find::name if /.jpg$/ },
  $localdir
);

foreach (@filefound){
  my @result = split('/images/p/',@filefound);
  foreach (@result) { print "$_  \n";} 
}
```

Comment: Some example input/wanted output of these filenames/paths would make this question about 10 times easier to answer.

Comment: so I want to see 
images/p/n/d/PLENTY-WD162
images/p/n/d/PLENTY-WD162
images/p/n/d/Y-UY11
images/p/n/d/Y-UY12
images/p/n/dt/EIGH-WD180
images/p/n/dt/EIGH-WD180
to come out without duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over @filefound but then not using the element for the current iteration.
And you are passing File::Find 'images/p', so your found names are not going to start '/images/p/'.

Try:

```
my @result = split('images/p/', $_);
```

Also, you say something about everything before the _; that doesn't appear to be anything like what your code is doing.

Consider using [File::Basename](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aBasename) if you need just part of a full path.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ysth, I am getting the file path using File::Find. I used the split('_',$ _ ) and it got me the file name before the _ and after the _ . How do I just access or store the part before the _ in array that I can use for uniq to remove the duplicates.
Thanks

Comment: I actually got the way to access the element I was looking for .
Thanks for helping me figure out the Split() function.

Comment: `($before) = split(/_/, $_);`  or `$before = ( split(/_/, $_) )[0];`

Comment: but is there a way I can store this in an array ?? I mean like @before ? as I will be using it to remove the duplicates in the array. Any suggestions please ? Thanks

Comment: @Jassi Are you asking how to store values in arrays?

Comment: No my question was on how to access the values stored in $before but I guess I know now how to access it. Now the problem I am running in is the removing duplicate characters which my code is not doing . I can post the code as an answer here ...